# warning: failed prop type: invalid prop 'backgroundcolor' supplied to view:

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a hex color which is received through prop in this file, The hex code is '#BE2625'. In  it is correctly displayed but when i apply the same to backgroundColor the color is not displayed, Rather it throws me an warning

> warning: failed prop type: invalid prop 'backgroundcolor' supplied to view:'#BE2625' Valid Color formats are .......

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native'


export default class Color extends React.Component {

  
  render() {

    const {Color} = this.props;
    
    return (
   <View style={[styles.bodyColor, {backgroundColor: `'${Color}'` }]}>
    <Text style={styles.hex}>  {Color} </Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bodyColor :{
        height:50,
        margin:10,
       
        
    },

    hex :{
        textAlign:'center',
        fontSize: 22,
        padding:10
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `'` characters in your color string:

```
<View style={[styles.bodyColor, {backgroundColor: `'${Color}'` }]}>
                                                   ^
                                                   this one here
```

You should remove them and use:

```
<View style={[styles.bodyColor, {backgroundColor: `${Color}` }]}>
```